# Redeclaration of enumerator

Tags: c++

I got an error: redeclaration of enumerator message when I compile my codes, please kindly see the code below from my foo.h header file,

```
//foo.h

struct FG
{
   enum
   {
      black = 1,
      red   = 2,
      green = 3
   };
};

struct BG
{
   enum
   {
      black = 1,
      red   = 2,
      green = 3
   };
};
```

My question is, why I am getting the enumerator redeclaration? my enums are in the different structs, so I can use the following,

```
BG::black
FB::black
```

here is the exact error

```
/home/sasayins/foobar/foo.h:10: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘black’
/home/sasayins/foobar/foo.h:3: note: previous definition of ‘black’ was here
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not including the header file twice?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code.  What, exactly, is the compiler error?  Is your header file included more than once?  Does it have proper inclusion guards?

Comment: yes, and I do have the inclusion guard.

Comment: edited, I added the exact error message.

Comment: Are you by any chance using a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler?  A C compiler would be obliged to complain as shown.

Comment: i see, is there any option in C compiler to remove the error, like in C++?

Comment: If your error is on line three, and you code is as shown, then you almost certainly don't have the proper code guards. (Not that that's necessarily the issue here, but you should have them as good practice.)

Comment: No; there is no way to avoid the error with the code as shown if you are using a C compiler.  Further, you would not be able to use the qualified names FG::black or BG::black to disambiguate them; C does not recognize double-colon as a valid symbol.

Comment: @sasayins: Why don't you compile C++ code with a C++ compiler?

Comment: The way to avoid the error is to type "g++" instead of "gcc" to run your C compiler :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, if you are using a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler to compile the code, then you will inevitably get the errors shown.  The code is only valid in C++, so you must use a C++ compiler to compile it.

Further, if you are using a C compiler, you would not be able to use the qualified names like '`FG::black`' or '`BG::black`' to disambiguate the names; C does not recognize double-colon as a valid symbol.

---

From the comments below:

> Actually the problem is in another file; my C file includes the header file, which is the header contains a C++ code file, so that is the cause of the problem. So my header file (foo.h) contains a valid code. Could you suggest a structure for C header file?

If you need your header `foo.h` to be bilingual in C and C++, you will probably do best with a single enumeration, losing the need for the `FG::black` and `BG::black` qualifiers altogether:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#define FOO_H_INCLUDED

typedef enum Colour
{
    black = 1,
    red   = 2,
    green = 3
} Colour;

typedef struct FG
{
    ...
    Colour  shade;
    ...
} FG;

typedef struct BG
{
    ...
    Colour  shade;
    ...
} BG;

#endif // FOO_H_INCLUDED
```

Note that the typedefs are needed to allow C code to refer to `BG`, `FG` and `Colour` without a prefix `struct` or `enum`; pure C++ would not need those typedefs at all. However, you are writing bilingual code and occasionally you have to write in a way that seems slightly stilted in one or the other language.

Comment: @sasayins: then maybe you should show the makefile?  Or the compilation command?  What is the extension on your C++ source file?  Using .cpp or .cxx or .C is conventional, but the latter (.C) could be confused with .c on a case-insensitive file system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually the problem is in another file, my C file includes the header file, which is the header contains a C++ code file, so that is the cause of the problem. So my header file(foo.h) contains a valid code. Could you suggest a structure for C header file? thanks